# How to remove escalate to case option from QnA tab salesforce

Tags: chatter, chatter-answers

I wanted to remove the "Escalate to case" option from the QnA tab, as per the document, I had removed that action from feed layout for that profile.
But still, while the user logs in and goes to QnA tab he still sees the escalate to case button. The profile has no moderate access to chatter.
[image]

In fact, I had delete that Action as well from the Feed Action list , but still in the QnA the "Escalate to Case" is visible

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for [Set Up Question-to-Case](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=questions_qtc_enable_qtc.htm&type=5)

> From Setup, enter Support Settings in the Quick Find box, then select
>   Support Settings.   To enable Question-to-Case in all communities
>   where Chatter Questions is enabled, select Enable Question-to-Case in
>   Communities.   To enable Question-to-Case in your Salesforce
>   organization, select Enable Question-to-Case in Salesforce.   Click
>   Save.

In the Lightning UI this is controlled by the Feed Item Layout located on the Admin Setup Page.

Admin Setup Page > Feature Settings > Chatter > Feed item > Feed Item Layouts

For

If you are using the [Chatter Answers Feature it is EOL with the Spring 18 Release](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Chatter-Answers-to-Retire-in-Spring-18&type=1)